# How to run jar files in python

Tags: java, python

How can I call this jar from python and also capture the results:

> c:> java -cp "C:\mallet-2.0.7\class;C:\mallet-2.0.7\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file nouncrf sample.txt

Comment: Its java question or python ?

Comment: Like any other shell command.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @DevEx I think others might find this question via google, so I answered it below. Does that resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subprocess:

```python
from subprocess import call
call(["java", "-jar", "foo.jar"])
```

You could also add other arguments like `-cp` to the list:

```
call(["java", "-cp", "<yourclasspath>", "-jar", "foo.jar"])
```